# An issue with argument "sortv" of function seqIplot()

Tags: traminer

I'm trying to plot individual sequences by means of function seqIplot() in TraMineR. These individual sequences represent work trajectories, completed by former school's graduates via a WEB questionnaire.

Using argument "sortv", I'd like to sort my sequences according to the order of the levels of one covariate, the year of graduation, named "PROMO".
"PROMO" is a factor variable contained in a data frame named "covariates.seq", gathering covariates together:

```
str(covariates.seq)
'data.frame':   733 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ ID_SQ           : Factor w/ 733 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6       
   7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SEXE            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Féminin","Masculin": 1 1 1 1 2 1 
   1 2 2 1 ...
 $ PROMO           : Factor w/ 6 levels "1997","1998",..: 1 2 2 4 4 3 2 2 
   2 2 ...
 $ DEPARTEMENT     : Factor w/ 10 levels "BC","GCU","GE",..: 1 4 7 8 7 9 
   9 7 7 4 ...
 $ NIVEAU_ADMISSION: Factor w/ 2 levels "En Premier Cycle",..: NA 1 1 1 1 
   1 NA 1 1 1 ...
  $ FILIERE_SECTION : Factor w/ 4 levels "Cursus Classique",..: NA 4 2 NA 
   1 1 NA NA 4 3 ..
```

I'm also using "SEXE", the graduates' gender, as a grouping variable. To plot the individual sequences so, my command is as follows:

```
seqIplot(sequences, group = covariates.seq$SEXE,
     sortv = covariates.seq$PROMO,
     cex.axis = 0.7, cex.legend = 0.7)
```

I expected that, by using a process time axis (with the year of graduation as sequence-dependent origin), sorting the sequences according to the order of the levels of "PROMO" would give a plot with groups of sequences from the longest (for the older graduates) to the shortest (for the younger graduates).

But I've got an issue: in the output plot, the sequences don't appear to be correctly sorted according to the levels of "PROMO". Indeed, by using "sortv = covariates.seq$PROMO" as in the command above, the plot doesn't show groups of sequences from the longest to the shortest, as expected. It looks like the plot obtained without using the argument "sortv" (see Figures below).

[Without using argument "sortv"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiSpm.png)

[Using "sortv = covariates.seq$PROMO"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyG9X.png)

Note that I have 733 individual sequences in my object "sequences", created as follows:

```
labs <- c("En poste","Au chômage (d'au moins 6 mois)", "Autre situation 
           (d'au moins 6 mois)","En poursuite d'études (thèse ou hors 
          thèse)", "En reprise d'études / formation (d'au moins 6 mois)")
codes <- c("En poste", "Au chômage", "Autre situation",  "En poursuite 
           d'études", "En reprise d'études / formation")

sequences <- seqdef(situations, alphabet = labs, states = codes, left = 
                    NA, right = "DEL", missing = NA, 
                     cnames = as.character(seq(0,7400/365,1/365)),
                        xtstep = 365)
```

The values of the covariates are sorted in the same order as the individual sequences. The covariate "PROMO" doesn't contain any missing value.

Something's going wrong, but what?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Best,

Arnaud.

Comment: For me it works fine even when the `sortv` variable is a factor. Please provide a minimal example showing the issue you are mentioning.

Comment: Hi Gilbert. Thank you for your reply. I've added further information. I hope these supplementary information will be sufficient to provide a minimal example, as you suggested.

Comment: Since we don't have the data, there is nothing we can run. Could it be that the original order of your data already follows the order of `PROMO`?

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure to understand; what do you mean by "the original order of your data"? The sequences are not originally sorted according to the order of the levels of PROMO, if you mean that.

Comment: By looking at your plots, I see that the order actually changes when using `sortv`. Compare, for example, the top sequence in the i-plots for `Feminin`!

Comment: Oh, you're right. Indeed, there are small changes, but not exactly as I expected.

Comment: So explain what you are expecting.

Comment: As I said, I expected that, by using a process time axis (with the year of graduation as sequence-dependent origin), sorting the sequences according to the order of the levels of "PROMO" would give a plot with groups of sequences from the longest (for the older graduates) to the shortest (for the younger graduates). But it is not the case.

Comment: Did you check that your data verifies the assumed relationship between PROMO and the sequence length (e.g. by crosstabulating PROMO and the sequence length)? I am quite sure this is NOT a TraMineR issue.

Comment: Yes, I checked the assumed relationship between PROMO and the sequence length (I crosstabuled PROMO and the sequence length). And there is a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Using a factor as `sortv` argument in `seqIplot` works fine as illustrated by the example below:

```
sdc <- c("aabbccdd","bbbccc","aaaddd","abcabcab")
sd <- seqdecomp(sdc, sep="")
seq <- seqdef(sd)
fac <- factor(c("2000","2001","2001","2000"))

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
seqIplot(seq, with.legend=FALSE)
seqIplot(seq, sortv=fac, with.legend=FALSE)
seqlegend(seq)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this example. I'm going to try to reproduce it with my data. I will let you know.